# SQL Server entity query

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm looking for a query for the entity below.

My model:

```
public class A
{
    [Key]
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public string FieldA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    [Key]
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public string FieldB { get; set; }
    public int AId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AId")]
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

I have an action result for class B like the one below:

```
    public ActionResult BsesIndex()
    {
        var Bses = db.Bses.AsEnumerable();
        Bses = Bses.Where(p => p.A.FieldA.StartsWith("text"));
        return View(Bses);
    }
```

It returns the any data from class B where FieldA from class A starts with "text".

I'd like to have similar action result for class A. It should return any Ases where FieldB from class B starts with any text.

```
    public ActionResult AsesIndex()
    {
        var Ases = db.Ases.AsEnumerable();
        Ases = Ases.Where(p => p.B.  // here I don't know what to write
        return View(Ases );
    }
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: `Ases = Ases.Where(p => p.B.Any(x => x.FieldB.StartsWith("text"));` or `All` instead of `Any`

Comment: It works, thank you very much.